# AJAX webpage to navigate on previous page

Tags: ajax

The data is displayed in `gridview` with paging on an AJAX enabled webpage. The `gridView` contains Item templates containing a link button. On `itemCommand` event, page redirects to display data in new page. When the `Back` button on browser is pressed, the previous state of the page doesn't load.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps set a cookie and use it to get the right page when initializing the gridview. Or modify the hash at the end of the URL (eg, add "#page2" to the location bar and read it back on init).

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this js stuff from google](http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/)

Answer (score -1):

Use [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/), it allows the state to be bookmarked and isn't affected by back/forward button.

Otherwise your options are:

- Telling the user to not press the back button.
- Putting the state in the url, e.g `mypage.asp#page_123` and using that to determine the state in your javascript at page load.